# Numberpicker value selector for android

Tags: android, xml

I Want Price Selector like image below:
[image: Image1]

This include counting from 0 to 99 and allow user to select by click the value
and display the amount in textbox like image.
Any help is Appreciated Thanks in Advance.

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it,It can be done my using NumberPicker

http://android--examples.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-use-numberpicker-in-android.html